# Downloading Google's maven repository

Tags: download, maven-repository

Does anyone know how to download entire Google's maven repository (to be specific from this link https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#android.arch.core) on a local machine so I can use it offline later.

I tried downloading it using `wget` with this command:
`wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html* https://maven.google.com/web/index.html`, but what this does is it downloads `html` and `css` files of this page, and that is it.

So my question would be is there a way at all to download it from this link, or any other link, and if there is what would it be?

Comment: Are you sure you want to download the whole Google repo which has more than 57GB (size according to  https://mvnrepository.com/repos/google )? Besides the Google repo common Andorid projects require Maven artifacts from other repos as well (e.g. Maven central).

Comment: The storage space would not be a problem, regardless how big the entire repo is. I don't have the internet to sync Gradle for the first time, I don't have it at all.  I just want to set up Android studio completely offline, but I just can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Install Android Studio on a system with internet access, open the project you want to compile and build it. Then check the user home for the `.gradle` folder, it should contain all the downloaded artifacts.

Comment: Does ```gradle``` have to be same version on both system with internet and system without internet for this to work?

Comment: Use the Gradle wrapper as everybody does, then you get the correct version for your project. Next to nobody uses an installed Gradle version.